# Backporting OpenSSL-1.0.1e to Debian Lenny (armv4l)

Tags: linux, compiling, arm, openssl, cross-compilation

I have an old embedded board that supports only Debian Lenny. I need to install `OpenSSL-1.0.1e` on it. If I download the source code then try to compile the source code, I get this error

```
ts7500:/home/openssl-1.0.1e# make
making all in crypto...
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto'
gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB_SHARED -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -Wa,--noexecstack -DTERMIO -O3 -Wall -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM   -c -o armcap.o armcap.c
In file included from armcap.c:8:
arm_arch.h:35:5: error: #error "unsupported ARM architecture"
make[1]: *** [armcap.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto'
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
```

how can I overcome that error?

```
Note: ts7500:/home/openssl-1.0.1e# `uname -a`
Linux ts7500 3.4.0 #83 Sun May 26 17:07:14 CEST 2013 `armv4l GNU/Linux`
```

ARMV4 is defined on https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/89dcf22/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/arm_arch.h

EDIT: If I add `#define __ARM_ARCH__ 4` in the beginning of the library, it suppress the problem and compiles the code without any problem. I wonder how correct what I did. I would appreciate a better solution (e.g., without modifying the library)

Comment: +1, just wanted to say thanks for posting your workaround here. I couldn't get the accepted answer to work in my environment (compiling for DNS-323), but the `#define` line seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't passed the right options to `Configure`. Make sure to pass the argument `linux-armv4`. If you're cross-compiling, in addition to `armv4`, you need to pass the path to the cross-compiler, as well as include and library paths if necessary.

```
./Configure --cross-compiler-prefix=/opt/gcc-arm/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- -I/opt/gcc-arm/include -L/opt/gcc-arm/lib
```

Comment: Gilles, Thanks a lot!! I wish I could upvote more, it was really useful help.